# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer not found by com.myproject.core [35154]

Tags: java, json, aem, json-lib

I use json-lib to convert xml structure to json format. My dependencies looks like this:

```
 <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
            <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- XML -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xom</groupId>
            <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

On the following line:

```
 XMLSerializer xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
```

The compiler throws the foolwoing error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.json.xml.XMLSerializer not found by com.myproject.core
```

Any Idea why I get this error?

Comment: Hate to ask the obvious, but do you import the class in your Java file or otherwise use the full package name to reference it?  More actual code would help.

Comment: Yes I did and eclipse does not show any problem. This problem occures to run time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by adding the missing jars to maven-bundle-plugin embeded dependencies

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Embed-Dependency>
                            ..
                            .....
                            json-lib,
                            xom,
                            ezmorph,
                            commons-collections,
                            commons-beanutils,
                            .....
                        </Embed-Dependency>
                  .............
```